# virtualbox - cannot move files within shared folder from java

Tags: java, file-io, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Alright, so I tried moving some files with java ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: baz -> ./foo/bar/baz: Operation not permitted
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:451)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1347)
```

It's a kubuntu guest on a win 10 host.

I *CAN* move the folder by terminal (`mv baz ./foo/bar/baz`). It just seems the java application didn't get the notice it can do that.

How do I resolve this (without moving the content out of the shared folder)?

**CODE**

```
String targetDir ="./foo/bar/"
Path bazDir  = Paths.get(MyConstants.BAZ_DIR);
DirectoryRemover.remove(Paths.get(targetDir).resolve(MyConstants.BAZ_DIR)); //just to be sure
Files.move(bazDir,Paths.get(targetDir).resolve(MyConstants.BAZ_DIR), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

where

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class DirectoryRemover {
    public static void remove(Path obstacle){
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(obstacle, new FileWalker());
        }catch(Exception e){
            //didn't exist / already deleted, etc.
        }
    }

    static class FileWalker extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code, please

Comment: Is there a `foo` folder with `bar` under it already? And do you have permission to write in "foo/bar"?

Comment: @nlopez see edit

Comment: @ElliottFrisch there is -- in fact, they are created by the application itself if they don't exist and the application already saves some files there.

Answer (score 0):

From all I can tell this is an actual issue in NIO. I observe similar issue with e.g. using Eclipse/jgit on a Ubuntu VirtualBox VM running on macOS.

The only suggestion I have is to use a local folder within the VM instead.